# Detect when element on top of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a task: on the page there are some specific blocks(div/sections, etc) with id and data-title. I need to detect when I scroll that one of these elements is on top of the screen and console.log its id and data-title. So, when the second element on the top I need second's element id and data-title in console, when third only third's data and until that element ends. How can I do that?

Here just an example of how it supposed to work, but now it detects when element is in view, but I need to detect when element is on top of the screen:

https://codepen.io/hamper/pen/NLWWjz?editors=0011

```
var titles = document.querySelectorAll('[data-title]');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(titles).each(function () {
   var $el = $(this),
    id = "#" + $el.attr("id"),
    elTopPosRelToWindow = $el.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
    elBottomPosRelToWindow = $el.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $el.height(),
    inView = ((elTopPosRelToWindow < $(window).height()) 
               && (elBottomPosRelToWindow > $(window).height()));  
   if(inView) {      
      console.log(this.id, this.dataset.title);
   } 
  });
});
```

Comment: May be `el.getBoundingClientRect()` will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxGNjG?editors=0011

```
if(Math.abs($el.position().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 5) {    
   console.log('On Top', Date.now())
}
```

Basically the logic is that find the difference between windows scroll position and the element. If value is less than a specific number, its at the top. I have set the value to 5. Depending on how accurate you want, you can increase or decrease the value. If you scroll fast, some scroll positions might be missed hence a range rather than a equals to in the conditional check

Comment: Interesting idea. Looks like what I need.